# Check if wrapper function is called?

Tags: javascript, function

I have this code:

```
function Q(a){
  function cElems(e,f,p){var l=e.length,i=0;if(e instanceof Array){while(i<l){f(e[i],p);i++}}else{f(e,p)}}
  if(typeof a=="string"){
    var b=a[0],c=a.substr(1),r=[].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName(c));
    return{
      setClass:function(b){cElems(r,function(e,p){e.className=p},b)}
    };
  }
}
```

I want to check if a wrapped function is called, i.e: `Q(".test").setClass("test2")`, and return something different if not, like so:

```
if(wrapped==true){
  return{
    setClass:function(b){cElems(r,function(e,p){e.className=p},b)}
  };
}else{
  return "no constructor was called";
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried that?

Comment: Tried what? My second lump of code is pseudo-code, there is no `wrapped` variable.

Comment: This question is unclear - what is a "wrapped function" in this case? Note that in `Q(..).x`, `Q(..)` is *always* invoked prior to `x` being resolved.

Comment: I want to return something different depending on if a .x is called or not.

Comment: You cannot, because `x` has not been invoked yet.

Comment: So it is impossible to check wether a subfunction has been invoked or not?

Comment: That is correct. It violates [causality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causality).

Comment: `Q` needs `this.setClass = function(){}`. What do you mean "if a wrapper function was called"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Q(..).x()`, `Q(..)` is *always* invoked prior to `x` being resolved (and invoked); this can be clearly seen with rewriting it as so:

```
var y = Q(..);  // this executes and the value is assigned to y
y.x();          // and then the method is invoked upon the object named by y
```

Thus it is not possible to alter the already-executed behavior of `Q(..)` based on the result of invoking `Q(..).x` - the object has *already* been returned from `Q(..)`.

Comment: Then how does jQuery do it? Calling `$(".class")` returns an array of elements, where `$(".class").hover(function)` does something different.

Comment: The result of the `$(".class")`, a jQuery object, did not change. Instead, jQuery then adds the hover event to all matched items, which *exist as part of the internal state of the jQuery object returned from $(..)*.

Comment: Indeed it didn't, but I can't call `element.hover()` outside jQuery - how can I make "sub-functions" like that?

Comment: It's not making a "sub function". $(..) is returning a *new (jQuery) object*, and all jQuery objects have the given function. Look at the example with `y` above - that is *all* that is happening. (Normal DOM elements, which are not jQuery objects, do not have such a hover method.)

Comment: But isn't that what I'm doing already, just with `{}` instead of `new Object()`? I just want `Q(".class")` to return an array of elements, and `Q(".class").x("param")` to run a function on the output of `Q(".class")`.

Comment: So return an object ("the output of Q(..)") that has an `x` method that correctly utilizes the internal state - either stored in the object or bound in a closure. Those are the pieces of information available and when they are available.

Answer (score 0):

You can see if a function has been invoked, like so:

```
var costructoed = 0;
function Constructo(){
  constructoed = 1;
}
function whatever(func){
  if(constructoed){
    func('It worked!');
  }
  else{
    func('Constructo was not executed');
  }
}
whatever(console.log);
Constructo();
whatever(console.log);
```

To see whether a method in an Constructor has executed it's like:

```
function Constructo(){
  this.someValue = 0;
  this.someMethod = function(){
    this.someValue = 1;
  }
  this.someMethodWasExecuted = function(func){
    if(this.someValue === 1){
      console.log('someMethod was executed');
    }
    else{
      func();
    }
  }
}
function whenDone(){
  console.log('someMethod was not Executed whenDone ran instead');
}
var whatever = new Constructo;
console.log(whatever.someMethodWasExecuted(whenDode));
whatever.someMethod();
console.log(whatever.someMethodWasExecuted(whenDode));
```